# Expanding element beyond size specified

Tags: html, css

I have this html and this css.

```css
.entry-content > .greyfruitdrawing {
  height:2000px !important; 
  width:2000px !important; 
  margin-top:40px;
}

.redletters1 {
  font-size:40px; 
  opacity:0.7; 
  color:red;
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height:1.6;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="greyfruitdrawing">
  <img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IMG_20191205_220426-300x201.jpg" alt=""width="300" height="201"class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-6978"/>
</div>
<div class="redletters1">SOME TEXT.</div>
```

The problem is that a) it won't expand by the size css is telling it to. b) elements are interacting in a way they shouldn't. Adjusting `greyfruitdrawing` affects position of `redletters1`

Site: https://4309.co.uk/about-us/

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to achieve? You want the red text to be on top of the image?

Comment: I'm wondering why, when the css tells it to be a width of 2000px, it doesn't do it?

Comment: You are setting the `width` and `height` of the parent `div` element. If you want the image to fill the divs size, you need to set its width and height to 100%. [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pd0s3xu9/)

Comment: OK. What about if I want to make it 200px. Can I do that? Also, it won't let me go to 200% for example. Why not?

Comment: I want to play around with size and make bigger than original but css won't do it. Why not?

Comment: Of course. [Check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0zr57Lb2/1/) `.greyfruitdrawing img {width:100%;height:auto;}` is needed as well.

Comment: So I have to specify the element `img` in percent and the element in px? Only then will the height change?

Comment: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-scaled-using-css-for-responsive-web-design.html - have a look here

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

There are a few problems with what you are doing here. First off, height and width are not properties that are inherited. In your example, you are defining the height and width of the **div** surrounding your image in your css, not the **image** itself, which is why it is affecting the "position" of the red lettering. The div is getting bigger and pushing the text downwards.

**Simply move the greyfruitdrawing class inside your image tag instead of your div surrounding it.**

Also, it is generally bad practice to use the !important property, although I don't know what the other classes you are linking to do, so maybe they are needed to override some presets you are using.

You have many different classes and properties trying to change the size of the image. I would recommend you do something simpler.

Either change the height and width properties within the  tag to match how big you want the image to be, or remove these properties and define it in your css.
Alternatively, if you want the image to fill the size of the div then I would recommend the answer by symlink.

The reason this is affecting the position of the red lettering is because you are making the div bigger, which is pushing the letters down the page. You can't see what is happening because the div is the same color as the background.

Using css to define height and width:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IMG_20191205_220426-300x201.jpg" class="size"/>
</div>

//notice the class is in the <img> tag and not the <div> surrounding it.

.size {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 2000px;
}
```

or defining height and width within the  tag:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IMG_20191205_220426-300x201.jpg" height="2000" width="2000" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and what I wanted to know. But the problem in removing `alt=""width="300" height="201"class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-6978"/>`is that it seems to affect the image quality. Why is that?

Comment: @Fresh Well displaying an image larger than the original size always reduces quality. Are you talking about just when you change the size, or do you mean that even if the image is the same size, that removing *alt=“” width=“300” height=“201” class=“alignnone size-medium wp-image-6978”* reduces the image quality?

Comment: Weird. I have no idea why that would be, but you can still keep those tags as long as you keep the !important tags in your css, although that would generally be bad practice. I would recommend finding a larger image or downloading it.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that. But now I've changed the class to `size` kept the tags, used important and it's responding to css`.size{height:500px !important; width:2000px !important; margin-top:
 40px;}`by allowing height increase but not allowing width increase. Even when I get rid of tags altogether, it's still only responding to height and not width increases

Comment: It seems to have something to do with portrait/landscape on mobile in that it's refusing to expand beyond screen width.

Comment: That is interesting. What is contained in the alignnone, size-medium, and wp-image-6978 classes; what browser are you using; what formatting is on the containers surrounding the image?

Comment: Yes. That's a point. What actually is a container, how do I find it and how do I modify it?

Comment: @Fresh a container is just anything that surrounds another element. Generally divs are the most common container used, but technically anything can be a container. You only sent a snippet of your actual code for your webpage so I’m  just wondering if other things could be affecting it. Are you using wordpress? It seems like you’re referencing classes and your picture using wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width of an outer container and then give the image itself a height and width of 100%:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.greyfruitdrawing img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.redletters1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="greyfruitdrawing">
    <img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IMG_20191205_220426-300x201.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="redletters1">SOME TEXT.</div>
</div>
```